# app not showing up on android market

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I finished uploading my app to android market an hour ago. 

 I did all the steps recommended [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html).

 I also have my copy off. Its paid and and I set up a merchant account too. 

 My app is not showing on the market. How long does it take to show up?

 And why is not showing up? 

 Is there any setting I am missing that I should do?

Comment: Did you check http://market.android.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be one of several reasons:

1. **Delay** - Market does sometimes take a little while to show new or updated apps.
2. **Manifest** - your `AndroidManifest.xml` may be too restrictive, so your app will not show up in the Market app of your test device (even if that's the same device you used for testing)
3. **User-error** - double-check you've actually saved and published the app. The new UI has caught me out twice already!

Comment: Just to *emphasize*, **it is most likely *delay***. P.S. Lucky Brahadeesh, less than an hour to show up! It could take several days, from other reports. *And before* showing up on google play's search, it should show up under https://market.android.com/details?id=com.name.package.app.your

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it takes a few hours until submitted apps (or updates) are showing up on Google Play. Maybe there is a short review process or some caching involved. If everything looks correct with the status info displayed to you, just get yourself a good cup of coffee and give it a few hours. ;)