# App not showing on Android Market even though published and activated

Tags: android, google-play

I have recently finished my app and after I save, publish activate etc. I return to the Market and search. . . Nothing. It comes up on the direct link (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ben.idroidprank ) but not up on the search. I have waited 3 hours but still nothing. If anyone can help I would be grateful!

Thanks in advance 
-Ben

Comment: Need more information. What permissions does it require? It should tell you on the direct link whether or not it is compatible with your phone.

Comment: My phone broke! So I am without an Android device! But it does not require any permissions.

Comment: much related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177624/app-not-showing-up-on-android-market

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my personal experience, it took about one day to appear on search. Until then, I give direct URL for my marketing purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I was just thinking that maybe people should look for my app in the search! And please tell me what you think =) https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ben.idroidprank

Comment: How do we find out the direct URL for our app?