# Time it takes to see my first Android app on market after publish

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app in market, checked the device list, countries list everything fine, but still not able to see my app through searching in market.

Want to know will it take time to become searchable in market ? like 3 or 7 days/hours ??

Thanks.

Comment: This is a wrong place to post this; we only do *programming* questions.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya then where he want to ASK?

Comment: duped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883362/app-not-showing-on-android-market-even-though-published-and-activated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will take a few hours -- how long exactly depends on the server load.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i see it now. No message on publish  so kind of searching for unknown error.

Answer (score 1):

To be the latest victim as of **11 Dec 2018**, Android App did take **6 days** to be live on playstore.

I have released an Android Apk on 6th Dec which gets visible to world on **11th Dec 2018**.

So patience will do the work guys, relax. No need to rush and look around.

Answer (score 0):

Its not predictable. Normally it takes an hour or two to appear on  the market from the time you published the app. Kindly ensure you post programming questions on stackoverflow and be patient till your app get published :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think after 1 or 2 hours you can visit your app through the google play url and can not search it.Maybe after 5 hours your app will be recorded by google play search index system.

One month ago,I receive a mail from google play.It warned me that some bug should be fixed and tell me

> To confirm that you’ve upgraded correctly, upload the updated version to the Developer Console and check and after five hours.

So I think ***after five hours*** the google play will record your apps and make search index for your app to be searched by users.