# how much time it take to release new version play store

Tags: android, publish

**My old apps have some bug that why I am releasing new version.**

After I release New version and I check it play store.

My new release in 1.03

but play store still showing 1.1 version.

How muck time it take to release new version any idea.

Comment: if you are updating then it will take 3,4 days

Comment: @rachna I update two times. My firebase functionality not working. So How I am going to check it. Is there any option so I can cheak after relesing.

Comment: you need to first check run that apk on your mobile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time it takes to see my first Android app on market after publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698172/time-it-takes-to-see-my-first-android-app-on-market-after-publish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes 5 to 6 hours only.. I've recently updated multiple times and it take maximum 5 to 6 hours.

Comment: Last time I update on 31 October. Two days early. Still, I am showing my first release. Did I miss anything.

Comment: you need to see the status on developer console on right side what's it showing may be you did something wrong that why it was on pending or some thing else

Comment: @SushenBiswas you sure your new version has been rolled out?

Comment: @It take 1 day for me. Thank you for answering.