# App not showing up in android market place/google play

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app to the android market about 3 hours ago and it shows up when I got to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.package.name but it won't show up in the search.

Also, when I am not signed into google it will appear if I go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=some.package.name&feature=more_from_developer however if I am signed in it will not appear in that list either.

In both cases, signed in or not, if I go to the apps page directly ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.package.name ) it will appear and say that it IS compatible with my device.  What is going on in the market? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: duped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883362/app-not-showing-on-android-market-even-though-published-and-activated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also experienced this with some of my apps. It seems that there are some kinds of caching strategies in place that prevent the item from appearing.

Just wait another couple of hours and check your application again. 
As long as the market says that the app is compatible with your device there shouldn't be a serious error.

Comment: @Mike - You accepted this answer, so any clarification on how long a delay you experienced?

Comment: The delay isn't consistent at all. It can range from 45 minutes to several hours in my experience. I tend to upload before bed and when I wake up it has appeared. I guess it is one of those "a watched pot never boils" type things.

Comment: We submitted an application 1.5 days ago and it's still not appearing in the Play Store. It can be found in the online market though.

Comment: Waiting for almost 24 hours here. When going to direct URL it sats page does not exist. It IS published and it is in beta but beta link does not work either.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it start reflecting in couple of hours but sometimes it can take upto 6 hours or more after publishing it to market.