# App not showing on google play

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play

I had a app submitted to google play store and it had been on there a while it was really buggy and i decided to pick back up development on it and completely revamp it.

Problem: i have forgot my keystore sign that i did the first app with so i decided to unpublish it and do a completely new upload of the app under a different name.

Now the new app doesn't seem to be showing on the google play store now matter how hard i look?

With the old app is it possible to delete this or is unpublishing it the right thing to do.

Can anyone give me some steps on possible ways to resolve this or ways in which you can check the status of your app submission?

Comment: After submitting app to Google play store you will couple of hours to wait.Then app will be visible. Btw what is name of your app

Comment: Hi joshiSumant its called World News App could that be the issue

Comment: I thing it should be waiting time only. how much time went since you have uploaded it

Comment: i changed everything over and i have been waiting about 24 hours so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced this with some of my apps. It seems that there are some kinds of caching strategies in place that prevent the item from appearing.

Just wait another couple of hours and check your application again. As long as the market says that the app is compatible with your device there shouldn't be a serious error.

The delay isn't consistent at all. It can range from 45 minutes to several hours in my experience. I tend to upload before bed and when I wake up it has appeared. I guess it is one of those "a watched pot never boils" type things

Refer: [App not showing up in android market place/google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play)

Comment: Hi Lokesh thought it was probably just a waiting issue but thought it would be worth asking incase it maybe something else. Thanks