# App not showing in Play Store searches

Tags: android, google-play

When I search for my app on the Play Store (called [*Battery Temperature Alarm*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharencareinfo.batterytemperaturealarm&hl=en)), my app doesn't appear in search results but when I search for "*batterytemperaturealarm*" in the search bar then it appears. Why is this occurring and is there a solution to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App not showing up in android market place/google play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play)

Comment: @deepak I did a [search for "batterytemperaturealarm" on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=batterytemperaturealarm&c=apps&hl=en) but your app didn't appear.

Comment: like Farbod, I can´t find your app, incompatibility with some devices, see my answer...

Comment: @Farod: that may be because i have not released in all country i have released this app only in some asian countries including india and china ,brazil and some african countries but not in europe and usa.even searching on compuer without connecting any mobile my app is not appearing by writing "battery temperature alarm" in search bar. However it appears when i write "batterytemperaturealarm"

Answer (score 0):

When your app will get more downloads, your app will get pushed up in the ranks for certain keywords. Maybe you just have to wait a couple of hours till it appears in the search for your keywords.

You can check your ranks on some websites like [www.appbrain.com](http://www.appbrain.com/) or [www.appannie.com](http://www.appannie.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you search the title of your app in the Play Store (i.e. "Battery Temperature Alarm"), that will be enough, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is the incompatibility with some devices probably including yours.

[image]

read more:

**[Android Supporting Different Devices](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html)**

Comment: even searching on compuer without connecting any mobile my app is not appearing by writing "battery temperature alarm" in search bar. However it appears when i write "batterytemperaturealarm". One more thing i want to add thai i have released this app only in some asian countries,brazil and some african countries but not in europe and usa.one more thing this app will support between api 15 and api 19 only

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Store's search results are ranked depending on downloads, reviews, compatibility with your devices, etc.

Your app seems to be quite new, and with a few downloads, so it will rank lower in comparison to more popular apps.

As I commented, searching for "*batterytemperaturealarm*" only returns one search result which is not your app.

Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play), which might help.