# App does not show in google play search or developer profile

Tags: android, google-play

App does not showing in google play search and in developer profile.

**Even though a few hours ago did it**

It appears in the direct link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superswell.find.difference

But does not show in.

Search:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=find%20the%20differences&c=apps
Others related searchs also, even though it did it until some days ago.
App Annie report also said it.

And by developer name doesnt show either:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=SuperSwell

**App was released a few months ago and updated a few days ago on octubre 25 2018.** -

- It wasn't published recently
- Google play developer page shows it "published" under status.
- Price and distribution page shows it published.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not showing up in android market place/google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play)

Comment: he says "I published an app to the android market about 3 hours ago " i didnt. It was published long before, and updated days ago.

Comment: See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **you just have to wait**, it's a *temporary issue*.

(like said in [App not showing up in android market place/google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play) even though the initial condition are not the same)

I had the same issue. Yesterday everything was OK. Yesterday night my app wasn't showing anymore even on my developer listing page.

Now it seems your app and my app are appearing again.

Edit: I just refreshed your listing page and now your app isn't showing again. I refreshed again an now it's back... The fix is probably being propagated.

Comment: You're absolut right. For anyone with the same issue it lasted about 12 hours.

Comment: By the way, we're not alone at all, check the androiddev subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9salhs/my_app_suddenly_disappeared_from_the_search/

Comment: Thanks! Gonna start using that sub for this kind of things for now on...