# My app is not showing in google play

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I uploaded my app to google-play about 18 hours ago, but it is not showing up. Developer console is saying "Published". I guess it should be viewable at url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.khasbuu.firstaid but it gives me 404 error.
What am I doing wrong?

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.khasbuu.firstaid"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <receiver android:name=".mongolcontent.SMSRemover" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".FirstAidActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowChapterActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowContactActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DonationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LikeActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name=".providers.FirstAidProvider"
        android:authorities="com.khasbuu.firstaid" >
    </provider>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Was it approved by Google? I suppose they review it before letting you publish but I may be wrong.

Comment: i had the same issue..after long hours of research i found that i forgot to give title for the app in the developer console. this will help you think

Comment: no there wont be any approval. If everything is fine, it will appear on Google play with in minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Developer Console homepage; ensure that it says "**Published**" at the right (this is the same in both designs). If it says this, and all your fields are valid (as in, if you edit it, and hit Save, no errors are shown), you may just have to wait longer. My apps are usually pushed within 2 hours, but I've heard reports of it taking up to 23 hours. I think it just has to do with Google's server traffic (how many apps are waiting to be processed), and other factors as such. It's worth noting that the process is entirely automated once you hit Publish.

Comment: Yes, console is saying "Published" with green tick.

Comment: Fair enough, you may just have to wait it out. [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883362/app-not-showing-on-android-market-even-though-published-and-activated) had to wait a full day for it to appear. Also, check under your developer name; it may appear there (there can be some caching issues for this type of situation).

Comment: At least that user's direct link is working. Mine is not :-/

Comment: It's working now because that was posted in October. What he's saying is that you can market your URL now (just double-check it), since it WILL work eventually.

Comment: In previous application I have used com.shine.xxx domain. Does it relate to the problem?

Comment: Nope. In one of mine I forgot to use the `com.` prefix, and my following applications have all been fine.

Comment: Waiting for 24 hours. Not accessible from browser and market on the phone.

Comment: I can access it just fine at this point: "First Aid in Mongolian", "Хэлж ирдэггүй хийсч ирдэг өвчин..."

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my app. I could find it by the .apk file name without .apk but couldn't find it by the name in the title field. This was OK with this since it wasn't really ready for prime-time anyway. By version 2.0 I was ready for a bigger audience so this was no longer acceptable.

The solution was to have somebody download it to their phone and give it a 4 star or higher review. It was then searchable by title in Google Play within an hour.

It didn't have any reviews before that so a lower review might have worked also...

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching contacts from user phone ? This is violating Google play agreement if you are fetching user contact without knowing user .I think this is the problem in your case

Answer (score 0):

As Eric said check whether you have moved your application to "Production", in pricing and distribution check whether you have selected countries, be careful about device compatibility and check whether you have excluded devices mistakenly, finally write app title and description related to your app properly.